# Div ScrollLeft or Right on each click Jquery

Tags: jquery

How to scroll a div left or right on each click by 30px?
Pls help

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("div").scrollLeft(30);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/stfzy/1835/

Answer (score 0):

First of you will need to get the current position of scroll.
use `$("div").scrollLeft()` for getting current position from left. and add 30 into it each time you click on button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    let pos = parseFloat($("div").scrollLeft()) + 30;
    $("div").scrollLeft(pos);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one ....

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
            var amount=30;
            $("button").on('click', function(){
                $("div").scrollLeft(amount);
                amount += 30;
            });
        });
```